# MySql start select from Match String point

Tags: mysql

I have a Table

```
col1     col2
---------------
aaaa  |  id=456,some_other_strings
bbbb  |  examno=3322,any_other_strings
cccc  |  id=587,some_other_strings
```

I want to start and end selecting only from the point where i match either of the strings (id= and ,some_other_strings) or (examno= and ,some_other_strings) on col2 so that final output looks like below

```
col1     col2
---------------
aaaa  |  456
bbbb  |  3322
cccc  |  587
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @x = 'id=456,some_other_string';

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@x,'=',-1),',',1) x;
+------+
| x    |
+------+
| 456  |
+------+
```

Comment: Worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using case and `substring_index`

```
select 
  case when col2 like 'id=%'
  then substring_index(substring_index(col2, 'id=',-1),',',1)
  else substring_index(substring_index(col2, 'examno=',-1),',',1)
  end col2
from demo
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e105347/14)